# Why does browser's pull footer tag inside body tag even after writing the doc. below example?

Tags: html, dom, html5-history

Why the Footer tag in HTML is always pulled inside the BODY Tag by browsers? why can not it be after Body Tag like Head Tag?

for Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
        <meta />
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Thank you </h1>
        <script src="js/app-1.js"></script>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="/">home</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Why the browsers pull this html footer tag into body tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the  tag goes into the  one

Don’t be confused between:

```
<head> / <body>
and <header> / <main> / <footer>
```

The  /  semantic refers to the Document global structure for which

```
the <head> mainly contains the document meta-data,
and the <body> contains the document content
```

The document meta-data included into  can be

```
Editorial Meta-Data
    <title>: The title shown in browser tabs, history, favorites, …
    <meta>: Keywords, Descriptions
    <link>: References to, icons, related documents
Technical Meta-Data
    <base>
    <style>
    <script>
```

Readmore here ..[qoura](https://www.quora.com/Do-we-put-the-footer-inside-body)

Comment: I think foot tag can be introduced for the purpose of adding svg icons symbol, html template tags and script tags, and leaving the body to pure content, where still dynamic content and styling can be added or removed as per the requirement. Thank you.